# How to change email and password in joomla through code?

Tags: php, joomla, virtuemart

I am integrating joomla in another system and i want to change email and password in joomla when i change email and password from my system.Is there any api or plugin todolike that?

Answer (score 0):

You can use jfusion to have common user in both Joomla and your system; provided both are php based. Link to JFusion is http://www.jfusion.org/feature/what-is-jfusion . If your system is based on any of the listed frameworks like dokuwiki, phpbb3 forum, kayako support OR joomla itself, then you can easily integrate it. Also if you have any other framework with which you want user integration then you can create a jfusion plugin. Jfusion works seamlessly with the frameworks i stated above.

You can check their documentation to create your custom JFusion Plugin http://www.jfusion.org/docs/doku.php?id=dev;intro